# Problema cuando busco mi tienda Prestashop en Google

Tags: prestashop, dominio

espero puedan por favor ayudarme a solucionar este problema.

Adquirí el hosting y dominio para una tienda en linea creada en Prestashop. Sin embargo tenia una tienda local (Oral Plus) con la misma plantilla configurada que se iba a manejar para la otra tienda (tienda médica). Lo que hice fue subir la tienda local y luego comenzar a editar productos e imágenes, pero para mi mala suerte no se porque cuando se busca el dominio en google aparece oral plus en vez de Tienda Médica, ya hice configuraciones en SEO + URL y edite el index, también genere el archivo robots.txt pero aun sigue pasando lo mismo.

Si a alguien le ha pasado o sabe como arreglar este problema lo agradezco mucho.

Me han dicho que es porque google ya lo tiene rastreado así, pero no se como solucionarlo.[image: Imagen del problema, al lazo izquierdo se puede observar en el buscador y en el otro directamente desde el dominio]

Comment: ¿La etiqueta `title` de tu `index` tiene el título correcto?

Comment: Tienes que pedir reindexación a Google, que es quien muestra esos resultados. Como te indica @zerocool lo puedes hacer desde las webmasters tools o bien esperar hasta que Google vuelva a pasar por tu tienda, lo que dependerá de tu Bucket.

Comment: Ya solicite la reindexación a Google y sigue igual, no se si se demora un tiempo o debería hacerlo de inmediato ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el panel de administación de prestashop ve a preferencias y luego a SEO & URLs, allí podrás cambiar esas configuraciones, luego debes hacer el reindexado con google.

De acuerdo a ésta respuesta en la versión en inglés de stackoverflow: [Pedir a google la reindexación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466360/how-to-request-google-to-re-crawl-my-website) indica que:

Hay dos maneras. La primera (y la mejor) es usar la opción "Extraer/Indexar como Google" en las herramientas de Webmasters siguiendo los pasos:

1. Ir a: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ and log in
2. Si todavía no lo tienes agregado, agrega y verifica el sitio
3. Click en el nombre del sitio que quieres administrar
4. Click Crawl -> "Extraer/Indexar como Google"
5. Opcional: si quieres procesar una sola pagina escribe la URL
6. Click en "Extraer/indexar"
7. Click enviar para indexar
8. Selecciona "URL" o "URL y sus links directos"
9. Click ok y listo

Con la opción descrita, siempre y cuando cada página pueda ser accedida por algun link en la pagina inicial o en alguna página que la enlace, Google debería reprocesar todo. Si quieres indicarle explicitamente una lista de paginas a indexar del dominio, puedes seguir las instrucciones en [Enviar SiteMap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668#addsitemap)

La segunda y generalmente opción más lenta es añadir la url [Submit URL](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url)

Comment: Ya realice el proceso y sigue igual, no se si se demora un tiempo o debería hacerlo de inmediato ?

Comment: cual de las opciones hiciste?

Comment: La primera opción

Comment: Intenta ahora con el primer paso que coloque en la respuesta, modificar las preferencias..{

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funcionó y ya se realizaron los cambios. Muchas gracias por su ayuda :D